# restricting database operation

Tags: hibernate

I have a question regarding restricting the Database transaction from Entity class while using hibernate annotation.
To be precise i am using hibernate with annotations and if i want to restrict my transaction only to save and view, where as update and delete operation should be restricted. This functionality needed to be attained from the Entity class, where am specifying the table and column name through hibernate annotations.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the exact difference between *save* and *update*?

Comment: @mindas : When we are adding a record to a row in the table for the first time then it is save (in my case this should be allowed )and if we are updating the record which is already saved in the database row then we are updaing the row(this should not be allowed).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a clean solution , but still it should work
You can achieve your intention using entity listener method

```
@PreRemove
@PreUpdate
public void remove() throws Exception{
    throw new Exception("cant remove/update entity");
}
```